# Parallax effect in CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't work anymore in buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

Tags: android, toolbar, parallax, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've been using a CollapsingToolbarLayout for a while and it always worked.
Since upgrading to

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

it isn't working anymore as expected. The Relative layout is rendered correctly under the statusbar, but the content inside the relative layout is rendered below the status bar (like the images, texts ect.) If I add a background color I can see the relative layout is rendered just fine.
Why would the content of the relative layout not match his parent anymore after the new design library changes?

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_properly_list">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/transparentText"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">





        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/genericproperty"

                />

            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/transparentBlack"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="50dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                    style="@style/extraLargeWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="2234 Mission Street"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSpareSubtitle"
                    style="@style/largeWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="San Francisco, CA"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSubtitle"
                    style="@style/largeWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_margin"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="San Francisco, CA"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
                    style="@style/mediumWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="a lot of rooms everywhere"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:title=""
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
...
```

Thanks for any help!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem were in some invisible element in collapsingToolbar, so try to remove all

```
android:visibility="gone"
```